# Conway's Game of Life Gliders break after a few generations

Tags: python, pygame, conways-game-of-life

So I tried creating Conway's game of life in python with pygame. I made this without watching any tutorials, which is probably why it is so broken. It seems to be working fine, but when I creates a glider it seems to just break after a few generations. I looked at some other posts about my problem and added their solutions but that didn't make it work either. I know this is a lot to ask for, but can someone at least identify the problem.

Here is my code. I expected the glider to function as do they are supposed to, but it ended up just breaking in a few generations

Code:
main.py:

```
from utils import *
from grid import Grid


running = True
t = Grid(30)

while running:
    pygame.display.set_caption(f'Conways Game of Life <Gen {t.generations}>')
    clock.tick(200)
    screen.fill(background_colour)

    if not t.started:
        t.EditMode()
    else:
        t.Update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    pygame.display.flip()`
```

grid.py:

```
import cell
from utils import *

class Grid:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.cells = []
        self.cellSize = size
        self.generations = 0
        self.tick = 1
        self.started = False
        self.GenerateGrid()
    
    def GenerateGrid(self):
        x, y = 0, 0

        while y < screen.get_height():
            while x < screen.get_width():
                c = cell.Cell(self, (x,y), self.cellSize)

                self.cells.append(c)
                x+=self.cellSize

            x = 0
            y+=self.cellSize

    def EditMode(self):
        self.Draw()
        if self.started:
            return
        
        for cell in self.cells:
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                if cell.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    cell.state = 1
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[2]:
                if cell.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    cell.state = 0

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_RETURN]:
            self.started = True

    def Draw(self):
        for cell in self.cells:
            cell.Draw()

    def Update(self):
        self.Draw()
        self.tick -= 0.05

        if self.tick < 0:
            for cell in self.cells:
                cell.UpdateState()
            
            for cell in self.cells:
                cell.state = cell.nextState
            self.tick = 1
            self.generations+=1
```

cell.py

```
from utils import *


class Cell: 
    def __init__(self, grid, position:tuple, size):
        self.grid = grid
        self.size = size
        self.position = pygame.Vector2(position[0], position[1])
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.position.x, self.position.y, self.size, self.size)
        self.state = 0
        self.nextState = self.state

    def Draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), self.rect)

        if self.state == 0:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (23,23,23), (self.position.x+4, self.position.y+4, self.size-4, self.size-4))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (self.position.x+4, self.position.y+4, self.size-4, self.size-4))
    
    def UpdateState(self):
        rect = pygame.Rect(self.position.x-self.size, self.position.y-self.size, self.size*3, self.size*3)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), rect)
        targetCells = []
        
        for c in self.grid.cells:
            if rect.colliderect(c.rect):
                targetCells.append(c)


        livingAmt = 0
        for c in targetCells:
            if c.rect.x == self.rect.x and c.rect.y == self.rect.y:
                continue
            
            if c.state == 1:
                livingAmt+=1

        if self.state == 1:
            if livingAmt > 3 or livingAmt <2:
                self.nextState = 0
        if self.state ==0:
            if livingAmt == 3:
                self.nextState =1
```

utils.py

```
import pygame

background_colour = (23, 23, 23)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 900))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
```

Comment: You count neighbors and update cells in the same loop, which does not work, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72389593/16462950).

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean by that. I put the process in which I determine how many living neighbors a cell has in a different loop but that provided the same result. Do you mean that I should update all the cells' states after I update them? If so, thought I was doing that already.

Comment: You must first determine the number of neighbors of each cell. After that you can update the cells. Updating a cell changes the number of neighbors of the neighboring cells. So you can't do these two steps at once.

Comment: Right.  Say you're looking at (0,0).  You update your array with the new state.  Now, when you go to look at (0,1), you have already lost the original state of (0,0).   When you're away from the edges, you're looking at 5 old states, and 3 new states.  You need to create the new generation in a new, empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `UpdateState` both counts a cell's neighbors and updates the cell's state. Since you call that function in a loop, both are done together, which does not work, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72389593/16462950). You must split the "count" phase from the "update state" phase.